# Trying to install scvi-tools in python, I have PyYaML 6.0, It asks for 5.4.1 and automatically installs it and then asks for 6.0

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pip

I tried to install scvi-tools using pip but got the following output. It seems to be a conflict with the PyYaML versions 6.0 and 5.4. I am using jupyter notebook if it matters.

```
!pip install scvi-tools
```

```
Requirement already satisfied: sniffio\>=1.1 in c:\\users\\angel\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages (from anyio\<4,\>=3.1.0-\>jupyter-server\>=1.8-\>nbclassic\>=0.4.7-\>notebook\>=4.4.1-\>widgetsnbextension\~=3.5.0-\>ipywidgets-\>scvi-tools) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\\users\\angel\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages (from cffi\>=1.0.1-\>argon2-cffi-bindings-\>argon2-cffi-\>notebook\>=4.4.1-\>widgetsnbextension\~=3.5.0-\>ipywidgets-\>scvi-tools) (2.21)
Installing collected packages: PyYAML
Attempting uninstall: PyYAML
Found existing installation: PyYAML 6.0
Uninstalling PyYAML-6.0:
Successfully uninstalled PyYAML-6.0
Successfully installed PyYAML-5.4.1
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
conda-repo-cli 1.0.24 requires PyYAML==6.0, but you have pyyaml 5.4.1 which is incompatible.
```

I tried downgrading to 5.4 but then it asks for 6.0.